# SQL Need to create a View that will pad and then combine 3 fields together along with a fourth static

Tags: mysql, sql, view, crystal-reports, padding

I have the needed code written in Crystal but then I run into an issue converting it back to a number. So I have decided to have the fields added together and padded in SQL as a view first.

I have two tables that I need to pull the data from STMT and CUST.

```
strMICRLINE := Chr(13) & "0603250694";
strMICRLINE := strMICRLINE & Right("000000" & Trim(Split({CUST.C_ID_ALPHA},"-")[1]),6);
strMICRLINE := strMICRLINE & Right("00000000" & ToText({STMT.STMT_NUMBER},0,""),8);
strMICRLINE := strMICRLINE & Right("0000000000" & Replace(ToText({@Total},2,""),".",""),10);"
```

`@Total` is the representation of

```
{STMT.UNBILLED} + {STMT.CURRENT_} + {STMT.OVER30} 
+  {STMT.OVER60} + {STMT.OVER90} + {STMT.FINANCE};
```

Comment: Consider formatting your post in future for ease of reading.

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: ok what is your issue here?

Comment: This can be easily handled in CR without a need to create something in SQL... you just need to be sure your text contains all numeric characters before you perform the conversion via `toNumber()`.